# Fundamental Group of $\mathbb{R}^2-(\mathbb{Z} \times \{0\})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

In [Fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (\mathbb{Z} \times \{0\})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2126722/fundamental-group-of-mathbbr2-setminus-mathbbz-times-0?noredirect=1&lq=1) it is said because $Y=\mathbb{R}^2-(\mathbb{Z}\times \{0\})$ has a countable points less than whole $\mathbb{R}^2$, then at each point we can retract the space into circles, and finally the space can retract to a wedge of infinite countable circles.
Could anyone elaborate this more? Thank you.

Comment: What is the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$?  Use this intuition for the example.

Comment: What more do you need?  Enlarge each point into a circle of radius 1/2.  Now you have a long line of tangent circles (a chain of beads).  Now slide each tangent circle down to the same point of tangency on each.  (This cannot be done in the plane.)

Comment: @AlvinJin Intuitively I know the fundamental group, but it is difficult for me to do it formally

Comment: @Randall Yes I know the intuition, but I have difficulty to write it formally

Comment: Write *what* formally?  Do you want to write down an explicit homotopy equivalence?

Comment: @Randall yes the retraction

Comment: Fun fact: Every non-compact orientable surface is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of at most countably many circles.